# Ubuntu: setting environment variables

Tags: android, ubuntu, terminal, android-studio

I need set environment variables for Android Studio project EVERY TIME when reboot or close terminal. (Ubuntu 14.04)
For setting variables I use:

```
export KEYSTORE_NAME=/home/anna/Documents/keys/NAME.keystore 
export KEYSTORE_NAME_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
export KEY_NAME_ALIAS=NAME
export KEY_NAME_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
```

How can I set there variables forever?

Comment: You should ask this on http://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: Assuming bash is your shell, put the lines in `.bash_profile` in your home directory.

Comment: @Anna Android Studio contains READ ME ya Instruction file please read that. You have to execute the shell file the rest will be automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put those lines in

> /home/anna/.bashrc

or in

> /home/anna/.bash_profile

depending on which file you use. I think it is

> .bashrc

in Ubuntu by default.
If you want to make changes made to that file be effective without restarting run command:

> source /home/anna/.bashrc