# How to enable DEBUG logs in SNORT IDS?

Tags: debugging, snort

I would like to know how to enable DEBUG logs in SNORT (installed version snort-2.9.11-1.f25.x86_64.rpm downloaded from www.snort.org in Ubuntu 16.04). I cannot see any parameter related with this in snort command-line help. Is necessary to recompile it or something?

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for this. After some hours searching and posting this question, I somehow managed to get the answer almost right after posting :-/

From [jasonish](https://github.com/jasonish/snort/blob/master/doc/BUGS), to enable debug in SNORT:

1. Build from source code enabling that option with

   ```
   make distclean; ./configure --enable-debug; make
   ```
2. After that, enable the log level exporting the following variable:

   ```
   export SNORT_DEBUG=<debuglevel>
   ```
3. Finally, run SNORT. The value for `debuglevel` can be chosen from the list in `debug.h`

Hope this helps someone else besides me  ^_^

Comment: Where do you set this (2): export SNORT_DEBUG=<debuglevel>?

Comment: Since it is an environtment variable, it depends on the Operating System you are using (mine was Linux Ubuntu)

Comment: I have ubuntu! And where can I set it?

Comment: You already have an answer to that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253375/ubuntu-setting-environment-variables  Thanks for the upvoting if you found this question useful  :-)